# Drawing circles based on user input

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I am writing a Python code for a school project.  The program is to draw a number of circles based on the user input, (2-6 circles).  I have done that but now need to draw multiple rows of circles based on user input.  For example, if a user picks 3 circles I need to draw 3 circles by 3 circles.

```
#import tkinter and turtle
import tkinter as tk
from turtle import *
#ask for user input using tkinter
from tkinter import simpledialog
application_window = tk.Tk()
answer = simpledialog.askinteger('Request', 'number of circles(2-6)?', 
parent=application_window, minvalue=2, maxvalue=6)
#set position of turtle and define turtle
t = Turtle()
t.penup()
t.setpos(-200,-200)
t.pendown()
#draw appropriate number of circles using loop
i = 2
for i in range (answer):
   circle(30)
   penup()
   forward(60)
   pendown()
   i = +1
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't make us do your homework. Tell us the problem, tell us what you've tried, then ask a question. For example, "How do I make the turtle draw three rows of circles?"

Surround the `for` loop you already have with another `for` loop. Every time the outer loop runs, the inner loop will run to create one row, and then move the turtle down before the next iteration.

```
#import tkinter and turtle
import tkinter as tk
from turtle import *
#ask for user input using tkinter
from tkinter import simpledialog
application_window = tk.Tk()
answer = simpledialog.askinteger('Request', 'number of circles(2-6)?', 
parent=application_window, minvalue=2, maxvalue=6)
#set position of turtle and define turtle
t = Turtle()
t.penup()
t.setpos(-200,-200)
t.pendown()

#draw appropriate number of circles using loop
for row in range(answer):
    for col in range(answer):
        circle(30)
        penup()
        forward(60) # must be undone after loop
        pendown()

    penup()
    backward(60) # undo the backward on line 20
    backward(60 * col) # go backwards the length of the diameter times the number of circles
    right(90) # turn right 90 degrees
    forward(60) # forward the length of one diameter
    left(90) # turn back left 90 degrees
    pendown()
```

Comment: Again, thanks Jackson H, you are right that was bloody cheeky.  Extremely poor time management on my part and had to rush it.  Learnt my lesson!

Comment: @MikeGreen No worries. Notice also that I removed the lines `i = 2` and `i = +1` (which I assumed you meant as `i += 1`): the for loop redefines `i` to `0` immediately after you set it to `2` and `i += 1` at the end of the loop happens automatically because it's looping through elements in a `range`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm offering an alternate solution to that of @JacksonH for two reasons: first, if you're using Python 3 (and you *should* be), then you don't need to grab `simpledialog` out of tkinter, use Python 3 turtle's `numinput()` (and `textinput()`) instead; second, an aesthetic goal should be to have the turtle move as little as possible to achieve your result, even if that requires more, smarter code.  Watch the difference in how this solution draws the picture as opposed to the other:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

# Ask for user input

DEFAULT_COUNT = 3

screen = Screen()
answer = screen.numinput('Request', 'number of circles(2-6)?', default=DEFAULT_COUNT, minval=2, maxval=6)

if answer is None:
    answer = DEFAULT_COUNT
else:
    answer = int(answer)  # int for range()

# define turtle and set position of turtle
turtle = Turtle()
turtle.speed('fast')  # because I have little patience
turtle.penup()
turtle.setpos(-200, -200)

direction = 1

# draw appropriate number of circles using nested loops
for row in range(answer - 1, -1, -1):  # loop backward to use last iteration as a flag

    for column in range(answer - 1, -1, -1):
        turtle.pendown()
        turtle.circle(30 * direction)
        turtle.penup()
        if column:
            turtle.forward(60)  # not done final time

    if row:  # every time but the last
        turtle.left(90 * direction)  # turn +/-90 degrees
        turtle.forward(60)  # forward the length of one diameter
        turtle.left(90 * direction)  # turn +/-90 degrees

        direction *= -1  # reverse our sense of direction

turtle.hideturtle()
screen.exitonclick()
```